# Regular expression for blocking particular email domains from registering

Tags: php, regex, symfony1, yaml

I have a registration form that users fill with their email address (and password).

The web framework I am using (Symfony) lets me specify a regular expression for an email address to be "good-to-go".

I want to block some domains that are just spammers, let's say:

```
example1.com  example2.com
```

So I need a regex that means: "accept everything but email addresses from those domains"

How can I put together the regular expression for that?

I tried with:

```
/!(@(examples1\.com|example2\.com)$)/
```

But it doesn't do what it is supposed to do.

Can somebody help, please?

Comment: What flavor of what regex is this? Or if you don't know, which language / program are you using this with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony [allows you to do both positive and negative regular expression validators](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/10-Forms).  You'll want to do a negative one.

```
sfRegexValidator:
  match:        No
  match_error:  Email addresses from that domain are not allowed
  pattern:      /@(examples1\.com|example2\.com)$/si
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these (I don't have experience in Symfony):

```
^(?:(?!example1\.com|example2\.com).)*$\r?\n?
```

Taken from Regex Buddy's library, or the following:

```
^(?!.*example1\.com|example2\.com.*).*$
```

The last is my improvisation.